# Wrong JWT is generated using firebase/php-jwt

Tags: php, firebase, jwt

I am creating JWT using documentation mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server#use_a_jwt_library).

Everything is done as mentioned in the documentation.

Here is the [code snippet](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7e4b9dbe806c04d5c2f546a1ac37f01b).

When I am returning this token to android client, Android client throws following error.

> com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException:
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The
>   custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation.

I am not sure, what am I missing while creating token.

```
$service_account_email = "abc-123@a-b-c-123.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
            $private_key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----VERY LONG KEY-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";//See github link for key if needed

            $now_seconds = time();
            $payload = array(
              "iss" => $service_account_email,
              "sub" => $service_account_email,
              "aud" => "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
              "iat" => $now_seconds,
              "exp" => $now_seconds+(60*60),  // Maximum expiration time is one hour
              "uid" => $mobile
            );
            $token = JWT::encode($payload, $private_key, "HS256");
```

Here is the screenshot of extracted token using jwt.io
[image]

Comment: Please do not post code just as an external link, it's always best to post code directly into the question and then if you want link to an external fiddle

Comment: @Draken: Thanks for the edit. Will take care of this for future posts.

Comment: Have you found any solution?:)

Comment: @FlorinT. Not yet. We have decided to wait till new Firebase upgrade becomes stable and continue  with the old Firebase till that time.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing a similar issue when I was simply trying to run the **Example with RS256 (openssl)** from [firebase/php-jwt Readme File](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt#example-with-rs256-openssl).

I posted a question about the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75254791/jwt-token-generated-using-firebase-php-jwt-is-showing-as-invalid-token).

and based on the Answer and comments, I learned that the Private and Public keys in the example are incorrect.

I generated new key pair using the following commands (copied from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/ygotthilf/baa58da5c3dd1f69fae9?permalink_comment_id=3760416#gistcomment-3760416), the other options did not work when I tried.)

**Private Key**

```
openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048
```

**Public Key**

```
openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout -out public.pem
```

and I used those files in my code and now it's working fine and even getting verified on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)

Here is the complete code:

```
<?php

include '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\Key;

$privateKey = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/private.pem');

$publicKey = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/public.pem');

$payload = [
    'iss' => 'example.org',
    'aud' => 'example.com',
    'iat' => 1356999524,
    'nbf' => 1357000000,
];

$jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $privateKey, 'RS256');
echo "Encode:\n" . print_r($jwt, true) . "<br/><br/>";

$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, new Key($publicKey, 'RS256'));

/*
NOTE: This will now be an object instead of an associative array. To get
an associative array, you will need to cast it as such:
 */

$decoded_array = (array) $decoded;
echo "Decode:\n" . print_r($decoded_array, true) . "\n";
```

Screenshot from jwt.io:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Best.