# JWT Token generated using firebase/php-jwt is showing as Invalid Token

Tags: php, jwt, php-8.1, php-jwt

I am using [firebase/php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) for generating JWT Token using the following PHP Source Code

```
<?php
include '../vendor/autoload.php';

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\Key;

$privateKey = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOD;

$publicKey = <<<EOD
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC8kGa1pSjbSYZVebtTRBLxBz5H
4i2p/llLCrEeQhta5kaQu/RnvuER4W8oDH3+3iuIYW4VQAzyqFpwuzjkDI+17t5t
0tyazyZ8JXw+KgXTxldMPEL95+qVhgXvwtihXC1c5oGbRlEDvDF6Sa53rcFVsYJ4
ehde/zUxo6UvS7UrBQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
EOD;

$payload = [
    'iss' => 'example.org',
    'aud' => 'example.com',
    'iat' => time(),
    'nbf' => time() + 3600,
];

$jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $privateKey, 'RS256');
echo "Encode:\n" . print_r($jwt, true) . "<br/><br/>";

$decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, new Key($publicKey, 'RS256'));

/*
NOTE: This will now be an object instead of an associative array. To get
an associative array, you will need to cast it as such:
 */

$decoded_array = (array) $decoded;
echo "Decode:\n" . print_r($decoded_array, true) . "<br/>";
```

The code works fine, I am able to decode the Token properly, but when I try to verify the token using the Debugger on https://jwt.io/, it's giving an error saying, it's an invalid token.

Here is the [JWT.io link](https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJleGFtcGxlLm9yZyIsImF1ZCI6ImV4YW1wbGUuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjc0ODAxMDk5LCJuYmYiOjE2NzQ4MDQ2OTl9.LZoiHKsmcABUO9BHreRU72NkRhCayqiqMs7yBPHJ-wJiz4jh-DfcD0GkDiuK16wMaihnxHAyX-DsVhMLlrY1ToX00xKZkNIkceRu4sAwDa4j7Yd1EakL_ln3UDdwaCv-f822pfvV21-wY2rqctuf-s87Wz3YLHcNHLwGqBEic0k&publicKey=-----BEGIN%20PUBLIC%20KEY-----%0AMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC8kGa1pSjbSYZVebtTRBLxBz5H%0A4i2p%2FllLCrEeQhta5kaQu%2FRnvuER4W8oDH3%2B3iuIYW4VQAzyqFpwuzjkDI%2B17t5t%0A0tyazyZ8JXw%2BKgXTxldMPEL95%2BqVhgXvwtihXC1c5oGbRlEDvDF6Sa53rcFVsYJ4%0Aehde%2FzUxo6UvS7UrBQIDAQAB%0A-----END%20PUBLIC%20KEY-----) with all the fields.

Note: I have read all the related questions and I am posting this question since they are unable to fix my issue.

Thanks in advance!!!

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key size is 1024 bit:

```bash
# key.pem is
# -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
# MIICXAIBAAKBgQC8kGa1p...
# ...
openssl rsa -text -noout -in key.pem

RSA Private-Key: (1024 bit, 2 primes)
```

Now let's [check](https://www.ibm.com/docs/sr/sva/9.0.2?topic=jwt-support) for minimum requirements for `RS256`:

> Required key size: At least 2048 bits

You have to create more secured key

Comment: Do you have the command to generate this key?
For the POC, I'm directly using the example from the PHP-JWT Readme.md file.

Comment: Do you have the command to generate this key? → how about [this](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-m&q=generate+rsa+2048+key+rs256&oq=generate+rsa+2048+key+rs256&aqs=heirloom-srp..) one?

Comment: Hi rzlvmp,

You are right, the keys that I generated were incorrect. the following commands worked for me to generate private and public keys `openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048`
and `openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout -out public.pem` respectively.

Best.